# CLRS: Asked to prove a result and then told to give a counter example

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am reading Introduction to Algorithms, and I am stuck at this execercise in the Appendix:

> - Argue for any integers $n \ge 0$, $j \ge 0$, $k \ge 0$ and $j + k \le n$.
>
> $${n \choose j + k} \le {n \choose j} {n-j \choose k}$$
>
> Privde both an algebraic proof and an argument based on a method for
>   choosing $j+ k$ items out of $n$. Give an example in which equality
>   does not hold.

Here I am asked to prove it and then give a counter example. I can't seem to find any problem with the proof or the couter example, $n=4$, $j=k=1$. Puzzeled!

[Here](http://clrs.skanev.com/C/01/11.html) is a proof:

> First, let's establish that, $j!k!\le (j+k)!$. Both sides have the
>   same number of terms, but the right side has $k$ terms more -
>   $(j+1)(j+2)\ldots(j+k)$ - that are greeter than the corresponding
>   terms on the left side $1\cdot2\cdot\ldots\cdot k$.
>
> Thus:
>
> $${n \choose j}{n-j \choose k}=\frac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}\frac{(n-j)!}{k!(n-j-k)!}=\frac{n!}{j!k!(n-j-k)!}\ge\frac{n!}{(j+k)!(n-j-k)!}={n \choose j+k}$$

Comment: What exactly is the question here? It's obvious that with $n=4$, $j=k=1$ we don't have equality, which is what the problem asked.

Comment: I'm closing this question because it turns out to stem from a misreading of the problem statement and is not conducive to answers of general interest.

Comment: @Gilles, yeah. I requested for mod attention.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't asked to give a counterexample to the proof, as that would be impossible.

Instead, they're asking for an example where *equality* does not hold, that is, the left hand side is strictly smaller than the right hand side. That's not a counterexample since the theorem states *less or equal*.